# NInject bind classes using third providers

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I've an interface and an abstract class:

```
public interface IBackend
{
    Backend.Domain.User me();
    //...
}
```

And the abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractBackend : IBackend
{

    protected Backend.Infrastructure.Provider.IDataProvider dataProvider;

    public AbstractBackend()
        : this(null)
    {
    }

    public AbstractBackend(Backend.Infrastructure.Provider.IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    #region User

    public abstract Backend.Domain.User me();

    #endregion
    //...
}
```

All of them are defined on an Assembly: `Backend.Infrastructure`.
I've developed several `AbstractBackend` implementations (in separated projects): `MemoryBackend`, `LocalBackend` and `WebApiBackend`.

Each of these implementations needs different information in order to be created:

`MemoryBackend` has no extra information according to `AbstractBackend`:

```
public class MemoryBackend : AbstractBackend
{

    #region Constructors & Initializers

    public MemoryBackend(Backend.Infrastructure.Provider.IDataProvider dataprovider)
        : base(dataprovider)
    {
        this.initialization();
    }
    //...
}
```

However, `WebApiBackend` needs some extra information in order to be configured:

```
public WebAPIBackend(Identity.UserIdentity userIdentity, Identity.ClientIdentity clientIdentity, Backend.Infrastructure.Provider.IDataProvider dataProvider)
        : base(dataProvider)
    {
        this.userIdentity = userIdentity;
        this.clientIdentity = clientIdentity;

        this.initialization();
    }
```

As you can see, `WebApiBackend` needs a `user` and a `client` are provided.

I've tried to solve that creating a `Provider` for each concreate backend in each project.

So then, I've several concrete inplementations of an `AbstractBackend`, I've several `NInject Providers` on each assembly.

The question is, from a third project I've binded all `AbstractBackend` implementation by convention:

```
public class BackendsModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("*Backend*")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom(typeof(Backend.Infrastructure.AbstractBackend))
            .BindAllBaseClasses()
            .Configure(c => c.InSingletonScope())
        );
    }
```

How can I get and bind each Provider with its Backend from a third project?

Example:

- UI has a AbstractBackend.
- UI has a NInject Module which's intended for loading whichever `AbstractBackend` implementation.
- UI looks at `MemoryBackend` constructors and it's able to activate an `MemoryBackend` object.
- UI looks at `WebApiBackend` constructors and it's not able to look for a `user` or client objects. It needs a provider. How to bind this provider which is on `WebApiBackend` assembly?

As far I'm able to figure out, a possible solution would be to load NInject Modules provided on each `Backend` implementation assembly.

So then, I would be able to create NInject modules on each `Backend` implementation, and then UI would be able to load these modules...

Comment: The modules are one possible approach, the other is, that the composition root's assembly defined how to bind all of the types. Can i ask you a question in turn: Why aren't you binding `UserIdentity` and `ClientIdentity`? Where are they coming from?

Comment: `UserIdentity` and `ClientIdentiy` are specific classes of `WebApiClient`. You've commented that composition root's assembly (UI) defines how to biond all of the types; I not quite figure out what do you mean...

Comment: Yeah, but what's the reason you need a provider for the `xxxIdentity` and you cannot just bind it? Then the convention binding for the backends would be good enough.
Re composition root: idea is to move *all* binding code to the composition root assembly (=> UI). Means it needs to know about all things which need to be bound. When you make a change in Assembly  D, you may have to adapt bindings in the composition root assembly. Assembly D will not have any binding / ninject code at all.